# Using Appendix prefix for figures in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and need help with the number of figures in appendices in the table of figures. Currently, they are just numbered,

1. Figure caption ............ p193

but I'd like them to appear as

A.1. Figure caption ......... p193

This is for my dissertation, and I've inherited some formatting code from previous graduate students. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\APPENDIX}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{chapter}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}: #2}%
\pagestyle{plain}%
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\singlespace%
\begin{center}% 
\large
\textbf{Appendix #1: #2}\\%
\normalsize
\end{center}%
\doublespace%
\vspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\newpage
\appendix
\appendix{A}{TITLE OF APPENDIX}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{dummy}
\caption{dummy caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you a different approach. Using a manual formatting for your appendices implies too much work: you'll have to correct counters, marks, ToC entries, amongst others. Instead, you can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to easily change the chapter format in appendices, allowing you to use `\chapter` for your appendices and thus solving automatically all problems mentioned above; in particular, you recover the desired numbering for floats in the appendices.

In comments it has been mentioned that a colon must appear between the number and the title for ToC entries corresponding to appendices, and that chapter and section entries should have leading dots; this can be achieved with the help of the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\AppChap{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\appendixname\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{1em}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{\vspace{10pt}\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel:]{1.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{\vspace{10pt}\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{1.25em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.25em}}
  {\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]{}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}

\apptocmd{\appendix}{\AppChap}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{A regular chapter}
\section{A regular section}
\newpage
\appendix
\chapter{TITLE OF APPENDIX}
\section{A section in appendix}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{dummy}
\caption{dummy caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

An image of the LoF:

[image]

Comment: That works well! The only problem it gives me is that the colon after "A" in the table of contents disappears (have to add `\tableofcontents` to MWE to see it)

Comment: @lmxb please see my updated answer.

Comment: One last question, then I'll leave you alone. I need to have dots after the chapter and section titles leading to the page number. I was accomplishing this with `\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\normalfont.}`
but now the dots are gone. I tried putting this into the definition of AppChap, to no avail.

Comment: I've also tried using `\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}` (found in other thread) both before, after, and inside the definition of AppChap, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: @lmxb no need for `tocloft`; you can do all this with `titletoc`, instead. See my updated answer.