# How to to separate the main text Figures from those in the Appendix in List of Figures

Tags: tocloft, appendix

I'm writing my thesis and struggling to understand how to separate the figures/tables appearing in my `\appendix` from the rest of the document in the List of Figures/Tables.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350394/how-to-have-separate-list-of-appendix-figures) but not 100% how to use something similar?

Currently I'm including my subchapters in the root document containing preamble and the list of called packages as `subfiles`. I also have subfiles for the different appendices.
All of the figures and tables within these appendices get compiled fine into one common LoF and LoT at the start of the thesis - [image: see image].

Note the figures marked with prefix 'A' (for appendix A) are not separate from the rest and it would be ideal that they appeared after an "Appendix figures" heading.

Is there a way to manually add such a title or modify the `tocloft` code in the document class file to change this?

At the moment I've only added the command listed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130736/using-appendix-prefix-for-figures-in-list-of-figures) to try and change the behaviour of the Appendix headers in ToC, LoF and LoT but it has not affected the output.

I'd like to have a bold heading in LoF similar to that which appears in ToC in the image attached (which is because I created a new `part` in the document called "Appendices").

Is anyone able to help make it happen?
(Note I don't know which parts of the MWE are relevant here so I haven't included it and the preamble + doc. class + subfiles configuration is a somewhat complicated).

```
\newcommand\AppChap{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\appendixname\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{1em}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{\vspace{10pt}\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel:]{1.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[0.8em]{.}\contentspage}
}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]{\vspace{10pt}\bfseries}
  {\contentslabel{1.25em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.25em}}
  {\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}
  [3.8em]{}
  {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}

\apptocmd{\appendix}{\AppChap}{}{}
```

Comment: Did you check the answer suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81712/how-to-list-supplementary-figures-in-the-list-of-figures)? The problem seems to be adaptable to yours.

Comment: @florian cheers, yes this something I'd be looking for. I included `newfloat` and used `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={App. Figure},fileext=lsf,listname={Appendix Figures}]{appfigure}` as is written in that answer to declare a new list and the figures in the Appendix are now prefixed by the new `App. Figure` handle, but there are no new headings in the LoF? Presumably because I need a way to call that new `\listofsuppfigures` list, but I can't find information how to define it in the package documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the standard `\addtocontents{<file>}{<text>}` command at the start of your appendices. Along the lines of:

```
% start of appendices
\addtocontents{lof}{\textbf{Appendices}}  % put bold Appendices in the LoF
\addtocontents{lot}{\textbf{Appendices}}  % and the LoT
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, fab. Cheers Peter